# How can I log all cypress test results to a single xml file?

Tags: xml, cypress

I have setup multiple cypress test files.

For example `test1.cy.js, test2.cy.js, test3.cy.js`

I run the tests inside a docker container with the cypress/included:12.1.0 image and the argument  `--reporter junit`. I want to use the output of the `test-result.xml` file which is automatically generated to display all test results from all the cypress test files I have.
The Problem I am having right now is, that the content of `test-result.xml` is overwritten when a new test starts. (Changing from `test1.cy.js` to `test2.cy.js`)
How can I log all the outputs in a single File?

I already tried tweaking the settings of the reporter but the result stayed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cypress has documentation detailing how to generate separate result files for each spec here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Merging-reports-across-spec-files).

> Each spec file is processed completely separately during each `cypress run` execution. Thus each spec run overwrites the previous report file. To preserve unique reports for each specfile, use the `[hash]` in the `mochaFile` filename.

Per their docs:

```js
// cypress.config.js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporter: 'junit',
  reporterOptions: {
    mochaFile: 'results/my-test-output-[hash].xml',
  },
})
```

```bash
// or CLI
cypress run --reporter junit \
  --reporter-options "mochaFile=results/my-test-output-[hash].xml"
```

You can then use a third party tool, such [junit-report-merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-report-merger) to combine those result files.

If using junit-report-meger:

```js
scripts: {
    "merge-reports": "jrm combined.xml \"cypress/results/my-test-output-*.xml\""
}
```